# EXC_BAD_ACCESS loading int with fscanf

Tags: c, xcode, scanf

It's been a very long time since I coded in C, and I've spent about two hours googling how to properly use fscanf. As far as I can tell, this code is correct, but I'm getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS every time I run it:

```
int rasterWidth;
int rasterHeight;
FILE* f = fopen("scene.u2d","r");

if (f == NULL)
{
    perror("Can't open file!");
}

char m [2];
fscanf(f, "%s", m);
fscanf(f, "%d %d",&rasterWidth,&rasterHeight); // Getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS here

printf("%s %d %d",m,rasterWidth,rasterHeight);
```

I've verified that XCode is opening the proper file (it loads the first two chars correctly). scene.u2d looks like this:

```
U2
500 500
-1.0 -1.0 1.0 1.0
g triangle.raw
c 0.9 0.8 0.7 0.6 0.5 0.4 0.3 0.2 0.1
s 0.5 1.0
t 0.3 -0.2
```

Is there something obvious that I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: So i Just compiled and ran your code with no problems, Is the error somewhere else or is there more to this file? Oh and char m is not big enough to hold U2 since the %s will auto add a \0, so it needs to be m[3]

Comment: Um, how do you expect "U2" to fit in `char m[2];` ?

Comment: And even if you change it to `char m[3];` you absolutely **must** change the conversion specifier to `%2s` rather than `%s` so it limits the field width read. Otherwise your code is vulnerable to bad data.

Comment: Also, in case `fopen()` returns `NULL`, you should stop there and not just print an error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the man page for `scanf` says:

> `s`  Matches a sequence of non-white-space characters; the next pointer must be a pointer to character array that is long enough
>          to hold the input sequence and the terminating null character (`'\0'`), which is added automatically.  The input string stops
>                 at white space or at the maximum field width, whichever occurs first.

This means you need at least `char m[3]` for that input file because of the null terminator.

I would also recommend using `%2s` as your format specifier so you don't overflow the buffer.

---

If that's not the problem, have you tried running only the code snippet you posted? It works for me - I suspect there's some memory mismanagement before the posted code. Or, is your code actually something like:

```
int *rasterWidth, *rasterHeight;

fscanf(f, "%d %d",rasterWidth,rasterHeight); // this is definitely a bad access
```

Bad accesses are on scanf calls are often caused by passing uninitialised pointers in.

Comment: That was it - the null character. How silly of me! Thanks for the quick response!

Answer (score 2):

To elaborate on my comment and to clarify what I think is the problem.

```
fscanf(file,"%s", &buff)
```

Will put [string\0] into buff, so buff must be at least 1 character longer than any possible string that will be read in.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int rasterWidth = 0;
    int rasterHeight = 0;
    FILE* f = fopen("scene.u2d","r");

    if (f == NULL)
    {
         perror("Can't open file!");
    }

    char m [3]; //  or give enough space in buffer to hold any string -- 
                   // char m [256];
    fscanf(f, "%s", m);

    fscanf(f, "%d %d",&rasterWidth,&rasterHeight);
    printf("%s\t %d\t %d",m,rasterWidth,rasterHeight);     
}
```

I think this code will help,